# Composer packages, specifying package root

Tags: php, directory, composer-php

Perhaps I've simply missed something basic (*hopefully*) but I can't quite figure this out.

I have a pair of PHP projects, each initialized as a git repo/Composer package; `foobar/package-a` which depends on `foobar/package-b`.

`PackageA` is structured as follows:

```
PackageB
 +- src
 |   +- PackageB
 |       +- Namespace1
 |       |   +- <files>
 |       +- Namespace2
 |       |   +- <files>
 |       +- Namespace3
 |           +- <files>
 +- docs
 +- other
 +- things
```

`PackageA` is structured similarly:

```
 PackageA
  +- src
  |   +- PackageA
  |       +- <files>
  +- vendor
      +- <files>
```

Anyway, I'm targeting `package-b` as a dependency from `package-a`, just using the local git repository.

```
# PackageA's composer.json
"require": {
    "foobar/package-b": "dev-master"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "path/to/foobar/PackageB"
    }
]
```

However, from `package-b`'s side, I only wish to expose everything under `/src/PackageB`, excluding the `/docs`, and `/other`, `/things`.

I was surprised to learn that there isn't a `package-root` key in the Composer schema, to indicate that I'd like dependent projects to only pull from a certain directory:

```
# hypothetical in PackageB's composer.json
"package-root": "/src/PackageB"
```

Is there any way using Composer to indicate to consumers that the files are located somewhere other than the package's root directory?

Currently, I'm ending up with *everything* from the `PackageB` root (`/src`, `/docs`, etc.) in the `vendor` directory of `PackageA`.

---

#### Addendum

- I'm now aware of the [`exclude`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#archive) key, though I'm looking to actually re-root the package and not just ignore the other directories. Moreover, I'm not sure if that'd apply here anyway.

Comment: Why were you surprised? I dunno if it's available for VCS repositories, but composer differs between dev and no-dev packages. That's perhaps what you're looking for.

Comment: Yea, expanding on that as per our chat discussion, creating a release branch that omits the non-essentials (via build hook or something) would work, but that still leaves the directory hierarchy artifacts; eg: all the parent directories.

Comment: Not necessarily, see http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging :D - but well, exporting a ZIP might be more sane in your case... . Let's continue in chat.